# Why would a program run on a virtual device properly consume a web service, but when placed on the physical device it doesn't consume the service?

Tags: android, apache-flex, service, dns, virtual

I made a program in Eclipse that is supposed to run on an Android device.  I got excited when it worked on the virtual device, but when I deployed it, it doesn't properly consume the web service that lets you authenticate.  I'm using Flex to create the program, and the service is written in C# and hosted on IIS 7.0.  Also, we've had trouble here with Androids and DNS, so I've changed all of the references that I could find to the domain name of the server to the IP address of the server.

And, the service is not exposed outside of this network.

Comment: Are you creating a Native Android App or do you intend to run this app in a mobile browser?  If the service is not exposed outside of the network; are you sure your mobile device is in the same network?  ( AKA Using a Wifi connection instead of a mobile data connection)

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure to include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your Manifest file? I seem to recall this sometimes working on the virtual device without the  tag, but on a real device it is most certainly required.

Comment: it was actually a network security issue.  I got it cleared up with the network guy.  Thanks for the help thought!

Comment: Not a problem, congrats on fixing your issue!

Answer (score 1):

If service isn't exposed outside your network then application can't have access via mobile network. You either have to grant access to your network via VPN or just make some interface for your application which will make communication possible.